# EXCEL: Change row reference while dragging cells formula to left/right

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good morning, in advantage, thank you for the help.

I have this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("'Health - URLs Scrapped'!C"&C12)
```

I would like to, when i drag the cell to left or right, the new cell change the row reference. So, instead of:

```
=INDIRECT("'Health - URLs Scrapped'!C"&D12)
```

i would like to get:

```
=INDIRECT("'Health - URLs Scrapped'!C"&C13)
```

Is that possible?

Images attached to see the real table:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX instead of INDIRECT.

INDIRECT is Volatile.

Then use another INDEX for the Change:

```
=INDEX('Health - URLs Scrapped'!C:C,INDEX(C:C,COLUMN(L:L)))
```